# Making dynamic list of option menus with invidual variable

Tags: python, tkinter

I have trying to do list of options menus with Tkinter. 
Idea is that menu is created according to data which length can vary, so I need to do dynamic list of option menus. 
I have some simple example about situation, not final code what I'm working with. 
Problem is that I haven't been successful in creating array of StringVars so that I could have separate value for each row. In example variable is common for all rows, because I could not do such version where list of StringVars did not produce error.

Here is example:

```
from Tkinter import *

list1 = ['001 aaa', '002 bbb', '003 ccc']

status = ["On", "Off", "Unknown"]

testset1 = []
master = Tk()
variable = StringVar(master)

r = 0
for x in list1:
    x = x.split(" ", 2)
    Label(text=x[0], relief=RIDGE, anchor=W).grid(row=r, column=0, sticky=W+E)
    Label(text=x[1], relief=RIDGE, anchor=W).grid(row=r, column=1, sticky=W+E)
    apply(OptionMenu, (master, variable) + tuple(status)).grid(row=r, column=2, sticky=W+E)
    r += 1

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is a solution using a list comprehension: You just need to create the OptionMenu within an auxiliary function and return the variable you use.

```
from Tkinter import *

list1 = ['001 aaa', '002 bbb', '003 ccc']
status = ["On", "Off", "Unknown"]
master = Tk()

def create_option(r, x):
    x = x.split(" ", 2)
    variable = StringVar(master)
    Label(master, text=x[0], relief=RIDGE, anchor=W).grid(row=r, column=0, sticky=W+E)
    Label(master, text=x[1], relief=RIDGE, anchor=W).grid(row=r, column=1, sticky=W+E)
    OptionMenu(master, variable, *status).grid(row=r, column=2, sticky=W+E)
    return variable

variables = [create_option(r,x) for r, x in enumerate(list1)]
root.mainloop()
```